# FastAPI tests: dependency override for a class does not overrides

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I am having trouble overriding some dependencies for my tests using FastAPI app and TestClient.
I have successfully override other dependencies that are functions by using app.dependency_overrides, but I am having trouble with a class (I do think the problem is because it is a class, but it is just my guess).

I have the following files:

```
# assistant.py 
class AssistantProvider:
    assistants = {
        'single': SingleAssistant, # Both are classes having a method called initial_message
        'multi': MultiAssistant,
    }

    @staticmethod
    def get_assistant(name: str):
        return AssistantProvider.assistants[name]
```

```
# messages.py (actually is a router)

from modules.assistant.assistant import AssistantProvider
router = APIRouter(...) # I don't think the content is relevant

assistant = AssistantProvider.get_assistant('multi')

@router.post("/start")
async def start(data: InitialMessageBody):

    agent_conversation = await assistant.initial_message(data.user)
    return agent_conversation
```

My intention is to override/mock/patch (I have tried different approaches) the `assistant` variable so it actually has a mocked object, but it keeps using the real reference to `assistant.initial_message. In the test, I have done the following:

```
# test_my_test.py

from main import app
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from routers.messages import AssistantProvider


client = TestClient(app)

class MockAssistant:
    @staticmethod
    async def initial_message(user: str):
        return "Whatever message"


class MockAssistantProvider:
    @staticmethod
    def get_assistant(name: str):
        return MockAssistant

app.dependency_overrides[AssistantProvider] = MockAssistantProvider

def test_start():
    response = client.post('/messages/start',
                           json={"user": "foo"})
```

This is actually calling `MultiAssistant.initial_message`, but what I'd like is to call `MockAssistant.initial_message`.

Comment: Did you read the pytest doc and fastapi doc about testing and using fixtures ? 
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/fixtures.html
Take a look at fixtures and pytest_mock .

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked fixtures, but don't really know how that could help. I'm not in the case that I need pre-arranged objects or data, I need a specific class to be override. In fact, I just got to a solution using unittest's `patch` and `AsyncMock` to create a mock for my `assistant` variable at `messages.py`. However, I am not sure if it is a good practice to mix functionality provided by unittest and pytest, so I leave the question open a bit more to see if there are other suggestions.

Comment: From FastApi doc : 

To override a dependency for testing, you put as a key the original dependency (a function), and as the value, your dependency override (another function).

And then FastAPI will call that override instead of the original dependency.

Which I understand as : this is meant to override a function, not a class. So your guess was right. Why don't you override each specific function inside your class ?

Comment: Correction from previous comment : 
But I also found this : "self.dependency_overrides: Annotated[
        Dict[Callable[..., Any], Callable[..., Any]]"
Wich means you should be able to use it with a class as long as the class is callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app.dependency_overrides` API is meant to override dependencies provided by `Depends`; it's not an API to mock module variables used in your FastAPI app. To be able to use `app.dependency_overrides`, provide your dependencies via `Depends` API:

```py
from modules.assistant.assistant import AssistantProvider

router = APIRouter(...)


@router.post("/start")
async def start(
    data: InitialMessageBody,
    assistant: Depends(AssistantProvider.get_assistant),
):
    ...
```

---

If you want to mock a module variable, you can use `unittest.mock.patch`:

```py
# test_my_test.py

from main import app
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from routers.messages import AssistantProvider


client = TestClient(app)

class MockAssistant:
    @staticmethod
    async def initial_message(user: str):
        return "Whatever message"


@mock.patch("main.assistant", MockAssistant())
def test_start():
    response = client.post('/messages/start',
                           json={"user": "foo"})
```