# How to Correctly Implement Mocked Authentication in Pytest for FastAPI Application?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, fastapi

I am working with FastAPI and pytest to test an endpoint in my application. I need to mock the authentication dependency, but I'm facing challenges in implementing it correctly. My primary goal is to ensure that the mocked authentication is properly set up so that my tests can run without hitting the actual authentication logic.

### My pytest code

```py
import os
from typing import Optional
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from unittest.mock import patch, AsyncMock
from main import app
from tests.mock_data import test_roles_data

os.environ["TEST_ENV"] = "test"
client = TestClient(app)

async def fake_authenticate(
        apitoken: Optional[str] = None,
        account: Optional[str] = None,
        sessionHost: Optional[str] = None
):
    return {
        'apitoken': 'apitoken',
        'account': 'account',
        'sessionHost': 'sessionHost',
    }

app.dependency_overrides[app.authenticate] = fake_authenticate

@patch('routers.base.parse_params', new_callable=AsyncMock)
@patch('services.roles.Roles.get_json', new_callable=AsyncMock)
def test_roles_endpoint(mock_parse_params, mock_get_json):
    mock_get_json.return_value = test_roles_data
    mock_parse_params.return_value = ("custom_fields_value", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-31")

    response = client.get("/roles", headers={
        'apitoken': 'apitoken',
        'account': 'account',
        'sessionHost': 'sessionHost',
    },
                          params={"start_date": "2023-01-01", "end_date": "2023-01-31"})

    assert response.status_code == 200
    # assert response.json() == test_roles_data


# Reset the environment variable after tests
del os.environ["TEST_ENV"]
```

However, when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'FastAPI' object has no attribute 'authenticate'
```

This error occurs at the line where I try to override the dependency with the mocked authentication function. I am certain that the `authenticate` function exists in my main application and is used correctly in my routes.

I am looking for guidance on how to properly mock the authentication in this pytest setup for my FastAPI application. What is the correct way to implement this so that my endpoint tests can bypass the actual authentication logic?

### Additional info

#### /main.py

```py
async def authenticate(
    apitoken: Optional[str] = Header(""),
    account: Optional[str] = Header(""),
    sessionHost: Optional[str] = Header(""),
):

    print(sessionHost)
    if (
        sessionHost
        and sessionHost[-20:] == "mydomain-staging.com"
        or sessionHost == "https://apistaging.mydomain.com"
    ):
        url = sessionHost + "/api/jml/templates"
    else:
        url = PF_API_URL + "/jml/templates"

    print(url)

    params = {"per_page": 1, "page": 1}
    accept = "application/vnd.mydomain+json;version=2"
    auth_headers = {
        "content_type": "application/json",
        "accept": accept,
        "account": account,
        "apitoken": apitoken,
    }
    r = await session.get(url, headers=auth_headers, params=params, timeout=30)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized")

    app.token_cache[apitoken] = {
        "account": account,
        "ts": datetime.now(),
    }


app.include_router(
    stats.router,
    dependencies=[Depends(authenticate)],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)
```

#### /routers/stats.py

```py
@router.get("/roles")
async def roles(
    request: Request,
    account: str = Header(...),
    start_date: str = None,
    end_date: str = None,
    profile_id: int = 0,
):

    custom_fields, start_date, end_date = parse_params(
        request, start_date, end_date
    )
    new_role = Roles(
        account, start_date, end_date, profile_id, custom_fields=custom_fields
    )

    try:
        await new_role.setup()
        result = await new_role.get_json()
    except NoDataException:
        result = {"Error": "No Data"}

    return result
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77473101/fastapi-tests-dependency-override-for-a-class-does-not-overrides/77473635#77473635) answer might be helpful.

Comment: Please attach the `/roles` route definition. How is the authenticate dependency injected into the route handler?

Comment: Just added the requested information :D

Answer (score 0):

In your test module import dependency function and use it's name to override dependency:

```
from main import app, authenticate

...

app.dependency_overrides[authenticate] = fake_authenticate
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more

Comment: In your test module import dependency function (`authenticate`) from `main.py` and use it's name to override dependency instead of `app.authenticate`

Comment: Made the changes but it still giving me 404

Comment: tests/test_stats_endpoints.py::test_roles_endpoint - assert 404 == 200

Comment: It seems like the problem is in the implementation of your route function (async def roles), not in the authorization. Try to add 'return {}' in the beginning of this function